# Search MySQL database, order results by COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a database table 'sales_list'. In this is rows of sales records attributed to a users_sales_guild_id. I'd like to query the table and order results by the number of sales made by each user, highest to lowest.

I thought this query would do it, but alas no...

```
$total_query = "SELECT *, COUNT(users_sales_guild_id) AS users_sales_guild_id_count FROM sales_list WHERE sales_entry_date BETWEEN '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-11-30 23:59:59' ORDER BY users_sales_guild_id_count DESC";
$total_rs = mysql_query($total_query) or trigger_error ("Query: $total_query\n<br>MySQL Error: " .@mysql_error()); // Run the query.
$num_rs = mysql_num_rows($total_rs);
```

This query returns 1 record. rather than a selection of records ordered by the number of sales by each user.

Your assistance is much welcomed.

Comment: count(*) will return one row unless there is a group by clause, what are the columns of the table ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty columns are: sales_id, users_sales_guild_id, users_sales_guild_new_id, users_dealer_code_id, users_dealer_code_new_id, users_dealer_name, sales_customer_firstname, sales_customer_surname, sales_customer_company, sales_vin, sales_commission_no, sales_model, sales_vehicle_class, sales_vehicle_reg, sales_rda, sales_active, sales_rrp, sales_quantity, model_year, sales_points, sales_entry_date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

count(*) will return one row unless there is a group by clause, so the query should be as

```
SELECT *, 
COUNT(*) AS users_sales_guild_id_count 
FROM sales_list 
WHERE sales_entry_date BETWEEN '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-11-30 23:59:59' 
group by users_sales_guild_id
ORDER BY users_sales_guild_id_count DESC
```

UPDATE : Its better to select col1,col2 ..... instead of * while doing group by - Point raised by InoSHeo

check this link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1201d/6

Comment: Even tough your query runs in MySQL without error, it is not correct SQL syntax because you are trying to fetch `SELECT *` but grouping by `users_sales_guild_id`

Comment: Understand @AbhikChakraborty. Makes the query a lot quicker. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

check this link if you would like to get details based on username http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1201d/4 here i have used type instead you can use username